# gcloud app deploy ERROR: Permissions error fetching application [apps/<PROJECT_NAME>]

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm deploying a simple Python 3 App Engine App (Flexi environment) by issuing following command: `gcloud app deploy --version=ver0-1`

and getting following error: `ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Permissions error fetching application [apps/<PROJECT_NAME>]. Please make sure you are using the correct project ID and that you have permission to view applications on the project.`

I can confirm the `account` and `project` are correctly setup when I issued following command: `gcloud config list`

```
[core]
account = GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_ID
disable_usage_reporting = True
project = PROJECT_NAME_I_WANT_TO_DEPLOY

Your active configuration is: [default]
```

Is there anything i'm missing on Permissions front? Im GCP Project Owner. Any addition API I need to enable in order to work with App Engine deployment, in Flexi environment

Thanks for any clue!

Comment: Try running `gcloud auth login` before deploying again, and tell us the outcome.

Comment: SOLVED! Was using project name instead of ID

Answer (score 18):

SOLVED! Was using project name instead of ID

Comment: You gotta be kidding me!! I spent a ton of time on this, this answer saved the day. Thank You!

Comment: Where did you set this up? (With the project name)?

Comment: @JoakimM in .gcloud config file ... or use ‘$gcloud config set project <PROJECT_ID>’ command on Terminal

Comment: For those copying/re-using configs from other GCP files, be careful because the full name of the project may change (pg-us-**n**-app-###### to pg-us-**p**-app-######)

Answer (score 3):

Solved this by running the following :

```
1. `gcloud config unset project`
2. `gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID`
```

where PROJECT_ID is your project id,

to see the correct project id,  you may want to run `gcloud projects list`.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having issues, check your billing. You need to have a valid billing account