# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) You do not have permission to access app [my-app] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to deploy my Google App Engine app through Bitbucket Pipelines. However I'm getting the following permission error while trying to deploy.

This is my bitbucket-pipelines.yml script:

```
script:
          # Install Google App Engine SDK
          - curl -o /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
          - tar -xvf /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz -C /tmp/
          - /tmp/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh -q
          - source /tmp/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc
          # Authenticating with the service account key file
          - echo $GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET > ./gcloud-api-key.json
          - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file gcloud-api-key.json
          # Linking to the Google Cloud project
          - gcloud config list
          - gcloud config set project $CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT          
          - gcloud app deploy --log-http --verbosity=debug app.yaml
```

Please find the debug log below.

```
DEBUG: API endpoint: [https://appengine.googleapis.com/], API version: [v1]
=======================
==== request start ====
uri: https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/my-app?alt=json
method: GET
== headers start ==
Authorization: Bearer [hidden]
accept: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 0
user-agent: google-cloud-sdk x_Tw5K8nnjoRAqULM9PFAC2b gcloud/155.0.0 command/gcloud.app.deploy invocation-id/234e7fc5072e448aaa6870de17b900f2 environment/None environment-version/None interactive/False python/2.7.13 (Linux 4.19.43-coreos)
== headers end ==
== body start ==
== body end ==
==== request end ====

---- response start ----
-- headers start --
-content-encoding: gzip
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,44,43,39"
cache-control: private
content-length: 126
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
date: Sun, 09 Jun 2019 22:39:11 GMT
server: ESF
status: 403
transfer-encoding: chunked
vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 0
-- headers end --
-- body start --
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
-- body end --
total round trip time (request+response): 0.389 secs
---- response end ----
----------------------
DEBUG: HttpError accessing <https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/my-app?alt=json>: response: <{'status': '403', 'content-length': '126', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'server': 'ESF', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control': 'private', 'date': 'Sun, 09 Jun 2019 22:39:11 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,44,43,39"', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
>
DEBUG: (gcloud.app.deploy) You do not have permission to access app [my-app] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 712, in Execute
    resources = args.calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/tmp/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 784, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/tmp/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/app/deploy.py", line 61, in Run
    args, runtime_builder_strategy=runtime_builder_strategy)
  File "/tmp/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 369, in RunDeploy
    app = _PossiblyCreateApp(api_client, project)
  File "/tmp/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 499, in _PossiblyCreateApp
    return api_client.GetApplication()
  File "/tmp/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/appengine_api_client.py", line 48, in GetApplication
    return requests.MakeRequest(self.client.apps.Get, request)
  File "/tmp/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/api/requests.py", line 85, in MakeRequest
    raise api_lib_exceptions.HttpException(error, error_message=error_message)
HttpException: You do not have permission to access app [my-app] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) You do not have permission to access app [my-app] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission
```

I already set a large list of permission to my service account and I keep getting the same error:

- App Engine Admin
- App Engine Deployer
- App Engine Service Admin
- App Engine flexible environment Service Agent
- Browser
- Cloud Build Editor
- Cloud Build Service Agent
- Environment and Storage Object Administrator
- Compute Admin
- Compute Instance Admin (v1)
- Compute Storage Admin
- Service Account Admin
- Storage Admin
- Storage Object Admin Viewer

Answer (score 1):

I found this post. [Deploy to Google Cloud with bitbucket pipeline](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/deploy-to-google-cloud-900820342.html)

First, you’ll need to create a Google service account key. For more guidance see Google's guide to [creating service keys](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys).

1. open up your terminal
2. browse to the location of your key file
3. encode your file in base64 format:  base64 -w 0 
   Note: for some versions of MacOS the -w 0 is not necessary.
4. copy the output of the command
5. go to your repository settings in Bitbucket and then Pipelines >
   Repository variables
6. create a new variable named KEY_FILE and paste the encoded service
   account credentials.

bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
image: node:10.15.1
    pipelines:
      default:
        - step:
            name: Build and Test
            script:
              - npm install
              - npm test
        - step:
            name: Deploy
            script:
              - pipe: atlassian/google-app-engine-deploy:0.2.1
                variables:
                  KEY_FILE: $KEY_FILE
                  PROJECT: 'my-project'
```

Comment: thanks for your tip, I tried to run this pipelines script, however it is showing permissions error as well as you can see

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Permissions error fetching application [apps/my-app]. Please make sure you are using the correct project ID and that you have permission to view applications on the project.

Comment: hi @czmarc try with this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49841209/5589964